# CrawlSpider derived object das no attribute 'state'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I try to use spider.state as described in http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.22/topics/jobs.html, but I get the error

```
MyCrawlSpider has no attribute 'state'
```

I try to use it in the **init**() function of a CrawlSpider derived class. Could this be the problem?

```
class MyCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    crawl_start = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyCrawlSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.state.get('crawl_start'):
            crawl_start = self.state.get('crawl_start')
        else:
            self.state["crawl_start"] = crawl_start
```

My goal is to have the crawl_start attribute to be always on the isoformat datetime string my crawler got started first, independent from when x resumes where started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy), `state` attribute is set on the spider by `scrapy.contrib.spiderstate.SpiderState` [extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#topics-extensions) in the [`spider_opened()` signal](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html?highlight=spider_opened#scrapy.signals.spider_opened) handler:

```
class SpiderState(object):
    """Store and load spider state during a scraping job"""

    ...

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        if self.jobdir:
            with open(self.statefn, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(spider.state, f, protocol=2)

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        if self.jobdir and os.path.exists(self.statefn):
            with open(self.statefn, 'rb') as f:
                spider.state = pickle.load(f)
        else:
            spider.state = {}
```

The signal is sent later than the `__init__()` method is being executed - there is no `state` attribute on the spider instance yet - that's why you are getting an error.